# Responsive page layout

Tags: 2016, page-layout

Have Any one tried to remove all page layout controls and add  HTML code instead?! Is it working?

I have a bootstrap template, I am thinking to replace the page layout code with bootstrap code!! Is it doable?! If NO , how can build responsive page layout?

Comment: Which page layout controls do you want to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to use bootstrap to create custom, responsive page layout.

You can remove the specific controls that you don't want in your page layout. Also you can add specific controls in your page layout using design manager.

You can add all your custom css/js references in content placeholder with `id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead"` and fields inside the content placeholder with `id="PlaceHolderMain"`.

Refer below sources:

1. [Create a page layout in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint).
2. [Steps to create page layout in SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-page-layouts-in-sharepoint-2013-using-sharepoint-designer).
3. [Creating a custom page layout in sharepoint 2013](http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: Thanks, at placeholdermain, can I add the front code in my bootstrap template, have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, you need to add your bootstrap template code inside PlaceHolderMain container.

Comment: Will try and feedback you